# Converting wget stdout and stderr to CSV for analysis

Tags: awk, sed, wget

I am using wget to do some integrity checking of a set of websites as they are undergoing a considerable upgrade which involves migrating databases etc. The old and new versions are called V1 and V2 respectively. The sites are built on a heavily modified version of Wagtail CMS.

One of the things I need to do is confirm that old URLs from V1 are properly redirected to new URLs in V2. My approach is to write a bash script that will:

1. Fully mirror the V1 user-facing site using wget
2. Create a set of V1 URLs with du, sed, and grep from the resulting on-disk file structure
3. Filter out URLs which don't require redirection in V2
4. Use wget to GET these URLs sequentially from the V2 site, ie replacing the original sitedomain.com with stagingsitedomain.com but keeping the rest of the URL intact
5. Convert the resulting stdout/stderr to CSV format

With the CSV in hand I will analyze the resulting stdout/stderr to identify whether there are URLs which aren't properly redirected.

I'm on the final step, ie step 5. Here is an example stdout/stderr for GETting three files:

```
--2021-12-28 17:58:42--  https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf
Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-12-28 17:58:42 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2021-12-28 17:58:42--  https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5
Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /documents/5/ [following]
--2021-12-28 17:58:42--  https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/
Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /en/documents/5/ [following]
--2021-12-28 17:58:42--  https://stagingsitedomain.com/en/documents/5/
Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-12-28 17:58:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2021-12-28 17:58:43--  https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf
Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-12-28 17:58:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I would like this to be converted to a CSV format like this:

```
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf,2021-12-28 17:58:42,https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf,2021-12-28 17:58:42,Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf,2021-12-28 17:58:42,HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf,2021-12-28 17:58:42,ERROR 404: Not Found.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,Location: /documents/5/ [following]
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,HTTP request sent; awaiting response... 302 Found
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,Location: /en/documents/5/ [following]
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,https://stagingsitedomain.com/en/documents/5/
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:42,HTTP request sent; awaiting response... 404 Not Found
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,2021-12-28 17:58:43,ERROR 404: Not Found.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf,2021-12-28 17:58:43,https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf,2021-12-28 17:58:43,Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf,2021-12-28 17:58:43,HTTP request sent; awaiting response... 404 Not Found
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf,2021-12-28 17:58:43,ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

The key steps from a mental logic standpoint to be:

1. Remove commas from the initial output and replace with ;
2. Identify individual stdout/stderr for GET of each of the three original files based on the double-newline
3. For each original file stdout/stderr the first column is the original requested URL, repeated, which is also the text of the first line in the individual stdout/stderr after the datetime text
4. The second column is the most recent datetime from stdout/stderr, so if there is no datetime on a given line then it inherits from above
5. The third column is the other text in each line

Columns 1 and 3 are critical, column 2 is nice to have.

I have tried various configurations with multiple levels of sed but am really struggling to achieve multiline replacement at the same time as using groups with replacement. My most recent effort at starting, ie parsing the first line of an individual file's stdout/stderr is:

```
$ cat wget.txt | sed -E ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n\n--[0-9-\s]{19}--  (https?:\/\/.*?)\n(.*?)\n\n/\n\n\1,\2\n\n/"
sed: -e expression #1, char 74: Invalid range end
```

I suppose in the end sed maybe isn't the best tool, possibly it's awk? At any rate, it seems very difficult given my current knowledge of these tools, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you require CSV? Text is text.

Comment: Simply adding quotes around the records would seem to do roughly what you want. Try `awk RS='\n\n' '{ sub/--[0-9-: ]+--  /, ""); sub(/\n/, ""); print "\047" $0 "\047" }' wget.txt >wget.csv`

Comment: Also have you considered curl?

Comment: @tripleee CSV is useful for analysis in Excel, eg so I can filter which URLs resolve to 404 rather than 200 and can count the number of items that resolve to each code. Thanks for the suggested awk command, unfortunately it's not working in GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1).

Comment: @konsolebox I hadn't yet, just because I was using wget for mirroring. Would it make this considerably easier?

Answer (score 0):

I would retrieve critical columns using GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
--2021-12-28 17:58:42--  https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf
Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-12-28 17:58:42 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2021-12-28 17:58:42--  https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5
Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /documents/5/ [following]
--2021-12-28 17:58:42--  https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/
Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /en/documents/5/ [following]
--2021-12-28 17:58:42--  https://stagingsitedomain.com/en/documents/5/
Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-12-28 17:58:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2021-12-28 17:58:43--  https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf
Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-12-28 17:58:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

then

```
awk '/^--[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{link=$0=$NF}$0{gsub(",",";");print link "," $0}' file.txt
```

output

```
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf,https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf,Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf,HTTP request sent; awaiting response... 404 Not Found
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/document5.pdf,2021-12-28 17:58:42 ERROR 404: Not Found.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,HTTP request sent; awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5,Location: /documents/5/ [following]
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/,https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/,Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/,HTTP request sent; awaiting response... 302 Found
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/,Location: /en/documents/5/ [following]
https://stagingsitedomain.com/en/documents/5/,https://stagingsitedomain.com/en/documents/5/
https://stagingsitedomain.com/en/documents/5/,Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/en/documents/5/,HTTP request sent; awaiting response... 404 Not Found
https://stagingsitedomain.com/en/documents/5/,2021-12-28 17:58:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf,https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf,Reusing existing connection to stagingsitedomain.com:443.
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf,HTTP request sent; awaiting response... 404 Not Found
https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/9/document9.pdf,2021-12-28 17:58:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Explanation: If line start with something appearing like date after `--` then set `link` variable value to last field (HTTP must not contain spaces, so there should be not problem with splitting in wrong place) and content of whole line (`$0`) to its' last field. For every line print `link` and that line with `,`s replaced by `;`s sheared by `,`, as `link` is only altered for lines which looks to be starting with `--`date this is link from latest such line. I use `$0` as condition to skip blank lines.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Would there be any way to end up with `https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5` in the first column of lines 5-17? It's important because this is a single URL from the V1 site and the goal is to determine whether that particular URL resolves successfully on the V2 site. So I need to be able to tie `https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5` on line 5 all the way through to the 404 errors on line 16 and 17.

Comment: @ChristopherBrooks if you need to remove trailing `/` then add `sub(/\/$/,"",link);` immediately before `print`, similarly you might remove `/en/` if following always holds true: there is at most one `/en/` AND it is always supposed to be deleted AND it is always `/en/` not for example `/fr/` or any other language code

Comment: It's not removing the trailing / but rather right now all these URLs are in column 1 lines 5-17 of the output

`https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5`
`https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5/`
`https://stagingsitedomain.com/en/documents/5/`.

On lines 5-17 in column 1 there should only be 
`https://stagingsitedomain.com/documents/5`.

That URL in column 1 should only change after \n\n in the input, for example between lines 4 and 6 in the input.

Comment: This is important because I'm following redirects which don't follow a convention like "add trailing /" or "add /en/", they may redirect to entirely different URLs.